# Dynamically set the height of Plotly.js table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly.js

I've come across the issue that table becomes scrollable if the number of rows exceeds table height.

By now height is set dynamically based on `clientHeigth` property

```
<Plot
  data={[
    {
      type: "table",
      columnwidth: [4, 1],
      header: {
        values: headerValues,
        font: { size: 24, family: "Montserrat" },
        height: 50,
        align: ["center", "center"],
        fill: { color: "rgb(179, 180, 180);" }
      },
      cells: {
        values: cellValues,
        align: ["left", "center"],
        font: { size: 24, family: "Montserrat" },
        height: 50,
        fill: { color: [tableColors] }
      }
    }
  ]}
  layout={{
    hoverlabel: { bgcolor: "salmon" },
    width: document.documentElement.clientWidth * 0.8,
    height: document.documentElement.clientHeight * 2.5,
    font: {
      family: "Montserrat",
      size: 20
    },
    paper_bgcolor: "#eaeaea",
    opacity: 0.01,
    plot_bgcolor: "#eaeaea"
  }}
/>
```

The workaround I've come across is to set `height` to `document.documentElement.clientHeight * 2.5` so it would be larger, than number of rows in **any case**, but that solution is quite ugly and not at all dynamic.

**My question is - is there any way to set table height dynamically based on the content to avoid scrolling?**

I wasn't sure if it's the right place to ask this question, but plotly.js community is quite uninformative and maybe someone here have come across similar issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found kind of solution. 
The structure of my table as follows: header (`1 line`), contents (`n lines`) and summary (`1 line`). Therefore height of my table should be enough to contain `n + 2` lines.

As we see from the code, all the data to be displayed in the `n` lines is contained in `cellValues` variable, which has the following structure `[ [], [], [] ]`, where each inner array represents a column.

So to calculate the `n` lines, we need to take `cellValues[0].length`

Then to calculate the whole height needed, I took `50px` as height for 1 line, and the answer is to set `height` in `<Plot />`'s `layout` property to **`height: (cellValues[0].length + 2) * 50 + 150`.**

Extra `150px` come from margins of the plot.